# ModalPopupExtender bypassing OnClick

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Hey so I am pretty new to asp.net, I am trying to create a website/form that takes in a bunch of data and do stuff with it.  I have a submit button that invokes a submitButton_Click method, but I am also having the a modalpopup that presents a "please wait" updatepanel while I do the processing on the server end on the same event. The problem is that it seems like the modalpopup is working fine, but it is surpressing my submitButton_Click method call. What do I do?

Also, if it possiable to have a default method that is invoked when the updatepanel opens? I want the panel to be the same everytime it pops up despite that I update it with the last time.

```
<asp:Button ID="submitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submitButton_Click"
            CssClass="buttons"/>

<asp:ModalPopupExtender 
        ID="modalProgress" 
        runat="server" 
        OkControlID="btnOkay" 
        TargetControlID="submitButton" 
        PopupControlID="progessPanel"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">

</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't *bypass* the click event; it just changes the client-side `onclick` to return false, which negates the postback. Honestly, I've always found this to be a pain in the butt. Forunately, there is a workaround:

```
<asp:Button ID="submitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submitButton_Click"                CssClass="buttons"/>
<!-- hidden button to satisfy the extender -->
<asp:Button ID="hiddenButton" runat="server" style="display:hidden" />

<asp:ModalPopupExtender 
        ID="modalProgress" 
        runat="server" 
        OkControlID="btnOkay" 
        TargetControlID="hiddenButton" 
        PopupControlID="progessPanel"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

By adding a hidden button you'll satisfy the requirements of the extender, and you can open the dialog in code-behind from the submit button's click event:

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //display the modal dialog
    modalProgress.Show();
}
```

Comment: I've seen this approach in the past but I dislike the idea of having a button just to "satisfy" the PopUpControlExtender thingy. I posted an alternative that *may work* -I didn't test it-.

Comment: @Icarus: Yea, I don't like it either. Unfortunately, sometimes you need to perform logic before you display the extender. I've been using the `RadToolTip` for a while now, mainly for this reason.

Comment: +1 My code didn't work. The ModalPopUpExtender requires a TargetControlID to be specified.